# Populating Publication list using a Data extension, is that possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, subscriber, cloud

I have set up a Smart Capture form to handle subscription preferences, it just receives the subscriber information and stores it in a DE, there are 5 boolean attributes in the DE that correspond to 5 newsletter options. My idea was to use those fields to add the subscriber to 5 different publication lists depending on which attribute is true.

Is that possible through some automation options Marketing Cloud has? I'm new to the Marketing cloud, and I'm trying to wrap my head around everything.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I was under the assumption that when you send an email using a data extension, and select a publication list, the contacts of the data extension were added to the publication list, but that doesn't seem like the case.

Comment: Your Assumption is correct : sending from a DE to a Publication list will actually add non-already members to it with the active status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No automation needed.

Sending from a DE, and specifying the Publication List for the Send will add  the recipients to the List, as Active Subscribers.

You could use the Booleans inside the Cloud Page Data Extension in Journey Builder as a criteria for a Decision Split to add the correct List to each Send.

Comment: @DavidBoada can you please consider accepting the answer if you problem is solved ? Thanks.